# Media metadata in HTTP header?

Tags: http, http-headers

I am working on an HTTP server specifically designed for serving image, video and audio files. I thought that it might be useful to include some metadata in the HTTP response header to describe attributes of the file such as dimensions, duration and codec. This would allow querying this info with a HEAD request, possibly saving the download of the file.

A naive example might look something like this:

```
X-Media-Duration: 1:23.4
X-Media-Dimensions: (1280px,720px)
X-Media-VideoCodec: h264
```

Are there any existing standards that perform a similar task? Or, is this not a good idea and why?

Thanks.